# Firebase Cloud function Messaging keep sending notification until user open it

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm stuck on an issue. I'm using Firebase Cloud functions to send a push notification. I use Topic subscription.

Here is the code :

```
export const sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return cors() (request, response, async () => {
    const { senderID, receiverID, messageSent } = request.body;

    const db = admin.database();

    try {
      const ref = db.refFromURL(`https://firebase-url/recentchats/${receiverID}/${senderID}`)
      const data = await ref.once("value");

      functions.logger.warn("DATA : ", data.val());

      if (messageSent === data.val().message && !data.val().read) {
        const senderName = data.val().sender;
        const notification: MessagingPayload = {
          notification: {
            title: `Nouveau message de ${senderName}`,
            body: messageSent,
          },
          data: {
            route: `/app/tabs/chat/${senderID}/${senderName}`
          }
        };

        functions.logger.warn(`${senderName} a envoyé le message : ${messageSent}`);
        
        const result = await admin.messaging().sendToTopic(receiverID, notification);

        functions.logger.warn(result);

        return null;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      functions.logger.error("ERROR : ", error);
      return error;
    }
  });
});
```

My problem is that the user keep receiving the same notification every minute until he decides to open one...

The log in firebase that keep repeating :

[image]

I don't understand why. I looked in the documentation but I didn't find any solution for my problem.

I hope that someone will have a clue about this issue.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Did you check the debug logs of our Cloud Function already to see if this code calls `sendToTopic` every minute? If not, it seems very unlikely that the problem comes from the use of Cloud Functions and you should be able to reproduce it by using the same code in a Node.js script. Eliminating Cloud Functions from the equation would simplify debugging.

Comment: Yeah I've already check it and it's called every minute

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Because I used an HTTP cloud function, I need to send a response to the client. I didn't do that so the function fall in timeout and I think Firebase retry the process that's why I keep receiving the same notification.

So the solution is to use

```
response.send("ok");
```

instead of

```
return null;
```

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem!  --- The divide-and-conquer approach that I commented about is very effective when debugging problems dealing with multiple APIs.